# How do i unstrip an object file?

Tags: gcc, kernel, elf, strip

How do i unstrip a stripped object file ?

Does eu-unstrip from elfutils can make this for me ?

I need this to convert a zImage kernel to vmlinux without recompiling.

This is apart of my script:

```
magic="1f 8b 08 00"
full_line=$(od -A d -t x1 zImage | grep "$magic" )
offset_full_line=$( echo $full_line | cut -f1 -d" ")
data_full_line=$( echo $full_line | cut -f1 -d" " --complement )
index=$[ $( awk -v a="$data_full_line" -v b="$magic" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}' ) / 3 ]
offset=$[ 10#$offset_full_line + $index ]

dd if=zImage bs=1 skip=$offset 2>/dev/null | zcat > vmlinux
```

But my result vmlinux has an unknown format because it doesn't contain ELF headers, so how can i recover those headers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question makes no sense.  If the object file has been stripped, then obviously the information is no longer there.  You've got nowhere to extract the stripped data from.

Comment: It could make sense. The ELF header he's referring to is probably just the magic to get it to boot, not for doing symbol lookups.